# How to configure Solr for one-to-many relationship

Tags: search, solr, flatten

I'm developing a search application using Solr that is required to search 'books' that are split into chapters. A book might look like this:

```
title: "book title"
author: "mr whoever"
chapters: [
    {
        title: "some chapter title"
        text: "blah blah blah"
    },
    {
        title: "some other title"
        text: "blah blah blah"
    },
    ... etc.
]
```

## Requirements for the search:

- The user is searching for *books* not *chapters*, so the top results must be the most relevant books overall, given all the chapter text inside.
- The user needs to see which chapters from a book have matched, information about those chapters and how many matches there were per chapter.

[image: results mockup]

---

## Progress:

#### Multivalued fields

Solr supports multi valued fields (i.e. multiple chapters per book) but it isn't possible to have two fields (title and text) per field on the book document.

#### Solr "Join"

I don't know if this is necessary. Each chapter will only be owned by one book so it seems like we could just put them all in one document without too much repetition.

#### Dynamic fields

Have fields like "chapter1text_txt", "chapter1title_txt" and "chapter2text_txt" for example and only join up the per chapter information independent of solr, so solr doesn't know that "chapter1text_txt", "chapter1title_txt" are part of the same thing.

**What is the proper way of configuring schema.xml to support and search this type of document?**

Answer (score 1):

### Document structure

So far the best solution has been using multivalued fields for both `chapter_title` and `chapter_text`, and enforcing a consistent ordering of these values in the upload documents, so the first `chapter_title` always corresponds to the first `chapter_text` and so on.

Here's the section of schema.xml:

```
<field name="report_title"
       type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="chapter_title"
       type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<field name="chapter_text"
       type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

This is a compromise because the index cannot know about this relationship between `chapter_title` and `chapter_text`, so it is impossible to ask for "chapters with **X** in the title and **Y** in the text".

### Match Counts

I still haven't found a way of doing this, but I'm considering using highlighting and counting the number of highlighted terms after asking for one large snippet covering the whole document.